# Import teams-js into Vue.js file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, microsoft-teams

I'm currently trying to implement the Microsoft Teams SDK into my Vue.js project.
I've already installed the npm package and refer to the package in my vue-file, but for some reason the value of my microsoftTeams alias will display as undefined.
Is there a step I've missed or why is it that way?

Snippet of my vue-file:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button v-on:click="getAuth()">do</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as microsoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js";

export default {
  methods: {
    getAuth() {
      console.log(microsoftTeams);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Did you initialized MicrosoftTeams js? you need to first initialize the teams js.

Comment: I know that you have to initialize the package first, before using it. The problem was that I couldn't access the package at all, because I missed the reference in data() like stated in the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting any variable still has to be declared in the data object unless you attach it to the window object.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button v-on:click="getAuth()">do</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as microsoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      microsoftTeams,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getAuth() {
      console.log(this.microsoftTeams);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Fixed the issue. Thank you so much! :)